# Can $V$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The main concept I'm struggling with related to this question is, if $V$ is a subspace of the one dimensional reals, $\mathbb{R}$, then I can write something like the following:

Let $B={[1]}$ be a basis for $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Then for some $x \in V$, I can write $x = a[1]$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Let $a=e^{j\theta}$ represent a unit vector in the complex plain. Then $x = e^{j\theta}[1]$ must be in $V$. However, this is only in $\mathbb{R}$ for certain values of $\theta$. We are not closed under scalar multiplication so I must conclude that you cannot define a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Is my conclusion correct or am I overlooking something fundamental?

Comment: I mean $\left\{0 \right\}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ and it's also a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. If you assume $V$ is non-trivial, you're correct.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that you can't just "switch fields" when talking about subspaces. So when you say $V$ is a subspace of the reals, implicitly you're saying $V$ is a vector space over the reals (or the rationals, whichever $\mathbb{R}$ is being considered as a space over).

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, the question is confused as it first refers to V as a subspace of the one dimensional real numbers, then V is suddenly a subspace over the complex numbers.

There is some truth in that the real numbers do comprise a one dimensional subspace over the complex numbers.

Comment: To make the real numbers into a vector space over the complex numbers, you need to use an extremely weird multiplication operation. You need the product of any scalar times any vector to be a vector (as required by the definition of "vector space".) So in this case, you need the product of any complex number and any real number to be a real number.  That's not the case for the usual notion of multiplication.

Comment: I phrased it badly. I was thinking terms of the fact that the complex numbers can be considered as equivalent to a 2D vector space. Thus the real and imaginary components can each be seen as separate  1D vector spaces.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why it's confused? I don't understand where the question violates a rule. I've chosen a subspace and a field and say the subspace is over this field.